# How to capture full http requests on express to request them again to my localhost

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express

I have a problem with an Express.js service running on production that I'm not able to replicate on my localhost. I have already tried requesting all the urls to production again to my local machine, but on my machine everything works fine. So I suspect that the problem comes with the data on the http headers (cookies, user agents, languages...).

So, is there a way, (some express module, or sniffer that runs on ubuntu) that allows me to easily create a dump on the server with the whole header so I can later repeat those exact requests to my localhost?

Comment: Simplest thing would be to just log it, then parse the logs.

Comment: You could use live http headers for firefox

Comment: @Paul yep, that's the plan B, but I'd prefer not to mess with the logs on production

Comment: @Derek how do I use firefox to get the http headers of the requests made to the server?

Comment: So im not sure what you mean by "messing with production logs", what I suggest is more about increasing the log level temporarily.  If you need to avoid hdd load in production, ship them to a third party log for a bit like Loggly or New Relic.  The answers so far are about inspecting your own requests, which won't help your problem.

Comment: @Paul yep, in the end I created an extra process running on production that was storing every request + headers in a serverless db (nedb). Then created another script that was reading that db and crafting the requests to my localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture network packages with https://www.wireshark.org/, analyze them and maybe find the difference between your local environment and the production one.

Comment: But how can I reuse a wireshark dump to make the requests to my local server?

Comment: You can make a script that read the dump and make requests to the server using curl for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a Proxy-Tool like Charles (https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to log your Browser Requests.

Comment: But this would only capture my own requests. What I need is to capture every request to the server until the one that makes it break appears.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem in production (on your server)?